# Django FTP server not able to login

Tags: python, django, ftp, django-ftpserver

I'm using [Django FTP server](https://django-ftpserver.readthedocs.org), it uses user authentication of Django.

Here is my code to create FTP user account

```
group = FTPUserGroup.objects.get(id=1)
home_dir = '/home/user/Workspace/ftpproject/ftproot'
account = FTPUserAccount.objects.create(user=user, group=group, home_dir=home_dir)
```

Above code correctly creates records in `django_ftpserver_ftpuseraccount` table.

Start FTP serevr with `python manage.py ftpserver 127.0.0.1:10021`

But I'm not able to login via FileZilla
FTP Server response is

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:10021...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 pyftpdlib 1.4.0 ready.
Command:    USER wpgjeQpgkDdVOMjFurYuvBxaRgfVoE
Response:   331 Username ok, send password.
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   530 Authentication failed.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I'm sure password entered is correct, I'm able to login with the same password for my django application.

Any Idea?

Will Django create the FTP directories? What is the path? What permission is needed?

Comment: Hi Mithun have you resolved this? I'm facing the same issue with my Django FTPServer. Thanks!

Comment: @acostela Have you experiencing this all times? what does django_ftpserver log say?

Comment: Hi i've just solved it. Was a network issue. My FTP server was in an internal loop interface so I couldn't reach it from the outside. Thank you for your attention :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the authentication issue by setting proper permission to Django FTP group from Django admin panel.

User need to be added to any of the FTP User Group and the group need to have `elradfmw` permission.

Create/Saving Django FTP User account object will create only database record, it will not create any physical directories; you will have to create it and set the path in home_dir field of FTP User account modal.

```
account = FTPUserAccount.objects.create(user=user, group=group, home_dir=home_dir)
```